# Can't use Setup() function in PyCaret: ValueError: One and only one of data and data_func must be set

Tags: python, installation, forecasting, valueerror, pycaret

I run the code below and it produces the ValueError above and I can't figure out why.

I have a different virtual environment where it works just fine where the only difference is I installed PyCaret with "pip install pycaret"  instead. I used the --pre PyCaret installation instead because the setup() function has the fh (forecast horizon) parameter in that installation.

#### Installed packages

```
pip install --pre pycaret
pip install openpyxl
install jupyter

python version 3.8.13
```

#### Code

```
from pycaret.regression import *
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.time_series import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xls = pd.ExcelFile('El-data.xlsx')
el_tavle = pd.read_excel(xls, 'El-tavle')

el_tavle.set_index('Fra_dato', drop = True,  inplace = True)

el_tavle['Maengde'].plot()

el_tavle['Maengde'].plot(kind = 'box')

el_tavle_setup = setup(el_tavle, 'Maengde', fh = 90, session_id = 123)
```

I expected the the setup() function to run without problems. Instead it produced an error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup call you specified both data and data_func

```
el_tavle_setup = setup(el_tavle, 'Maengde', fh = 90, session_id = 123)
```

equals to

```
el_tavle_setup = setup(data=el_tavle, data_func='Maengde', fh = 90, session_id = 123)
```

and what you wanted to write is:

```
el_tavle_setup = setup(data=el_tavle, target='Maengde', fh = 90, session_id = 123)
```

Be careful when passing unnamed arguments.